# get value from shared pref to setmultichoiceitems in alertdialog

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I have alertdialog with multiple choice items. I am able to display alert and able to select the checkbox the store in the shared preferences. Now how can i retrieve from the shared preference and maintain the checkbox state. the value storing in shared pref in format of [1,3,4] these checkboxes are selected. Please help.

```
final CharSequence[] ratings = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    final ArrayList selectedratings = new ArrayList();
    final boolean[] ratingschecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("checkedrate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("size", 0);
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        selectedratings.add(sharedPreferences.getString("selectedratings" + j, String.valueOf(selectedratings.get(j))));
    }


    for(int j=0;j<selectedratings.size();j++){
            int s = (int) selectedratings.get(j);
            ratingschecked[s-1]=true;
    }

    builder.setTitle("Select Ratings");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if(!selectedratings.contains((String)String.valueOf(which+1))){
                    selectedratings.add(String.valueOf(which+1));
                    ratingschecked[which+1]=true;
                }
            } else if (selectedratings.contains(which + 1)) {
                selectedratings.remove((String)String.valueOf(which));
                ratingschecked[which]=false;

            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            // editor.putString("checked", String.valueOf(selectedratings));
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedratings.size(); i++) {
                editor.putString("selectedratings" + i, String.valueOf(selectedratings.get(i)));
            }
            editor.putInt("size", selectedratings.size());
            editor.apply();
            Log.e("Shiva", String.valueOf(selectedratings));


        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: It's great working

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveToPreferences(String key, String value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_CONFIG,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Use above method to save to preference and below method to get it back

```
public String getFromPreferences(String key) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = prefs.getString(key, "");
    if (!value.isEmpty()) {
        return value;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The checkbox values are in arraylist how can i use the above code for array list to retrieve? I am able to save in shared pref editor.putString("checked", String.valueOf(selectedratings)); selectedratings is Array list.

Comment: getFromPreferences(arraylist.get(position).getCheckBoxValue())  ... you can try something this.

Comment: Modified the code able to save shared preferences but while retrieving throwing ava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0